# React Native - cancel on press

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I’m creating a game with react native that involves multiple users interacting with the screen.

Most of the time, it works fine, but there are times where it causes problems e.g someone leaving their finger on the phone, then other users presses not being recognised

I’m looking for a way to cancel the on press, after the tap has initially registered

Going through the docs for tocuhables, I’m not sure it’s possible through react native

Any suggestions welcome

Comment: did you try capturing the event and executing `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Event.stopPropagation()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manage complex touches then you'll want to use the [`PanResponder`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder).  "Cancel" isn't really an option, but you can definitely stop responding to a touch if certain conditions are met.

> there are times where it causes problems e.g someone leaving their finger on the phone, then other users presses not being recognised

The methods which come into play for this are the `*ShouldSetPanResponder` methods.  These determine whether the current touch should become the active touch.

```
onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (e, gestureState) => {...}
onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (e, gestureState) => {...}
onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (e, gestureState) => {...}
onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (e, gestureState) => {...}
```

---

The [`react-native-gesture-handler`](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/) library can make it a lot easier to deal with these low-level APIs.  It includes components like [`TapGestureHandler`](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/api/gesture-handlers/tap-gh) with standardized props like `maxDurationMs`, `numberOfTaps`, etc.